# Primary determinant for deciding if you should use ‘the’

Tags: definite-articles

In the following dialog, *both*

> ‘the people who we don’t know’ *and*
>   ‘Ø people who we don’t know’

might mean *either*

> ‘all the people who we don’t know’ *or*
>   ‘some of the people who we don’t know.’

‘*The people who ...*’ sounds more like ‘*all*’ than just ‘*Ø people who ...*’ according to some native speakers. However, it is IMPLIED/ FELT/ PERCEIVED.
In fact, some native speakers say ‘*the people who we don’t know*’ sounds no more than just ‘*some*.’ ‘*All* or *some*’ shouldn’t be the determinant.

What do you think is the determinant, then? Any and all insights would be welcome. What do you think is the determinant for deciding you should use ‘the’ or not in the following example? Some people feel you mean ‘all the people’ with ‘the,’ but it’s not the primary determinant, many people think. Would it be your mind that wants to emphasize the meaning of the relative pronouns that places ‘the’ there?

> (Suppose there is no context, explicit or implicit, that brings on the
>   definite article in front of ‘people’ and ‘ones’ other than, possibly, the
>   relative noun clauses ‘who we don’t know’ and ‘who we know.’)
>
> Tom: Although the/Ø people who we don’t know from our Sendai factory
>   came to the party, the/Ø ones who we know didn’t.
>
> Sam: Oh, I didn’t even know you have a factory in Sendai.
>
> (I wrote this dialog, thinking ‘we’ are Tom and some of his co-workers, and
>   that it doesn’t include Sam. Sam is from outside Tom’s company)

Comment: The people==all people; people we know == some, possibly all

Answer (score 3):

Starting from basics:

> ***the*** is the *definite* article (singular & plural)
>   ***a*** is the *indefinite* article (singular); for *plural indefinite*, no article is used.

So:

> ***The man/men*** refers to a *specific/defined* (or *definite*) man/men (whom you have already specified or subsequently specify); e.g.:
>    - *The man with the dog didn't clear up the dog mess.*
>    - *The men mending the road did a very good repair.*
>
> ***A man / Men*** refers to an *unspecified/undefined* (or *indefinite*) man/men (the actual man/men is/are *not specified/defined*; e.g.:
>    - *I saw a man walking his dog today.*
>    - *There were men mending the road outside my house.*

Likewise:

> ***The people*** refers to a *defined/specific* (or *definite*) group of people
>   ***People*** refers to any *undefined/unspecific* (or *indefinite*) group of people.

Back to the phrases in your question:

> ***the** people who we don't know from our Sendai factory came to the party*

refers to a *specific defined* group of people, namely ***the people*** from the Sendai factory **who you don't know**.
In that this is a *specific defined* group, it necessarily implies ***all of the people who you don't know***.
So, ***everyone*** from the factory that you don't know came to the party.

And similarly:

> ***the ones who we know** didn't.*

means ***all of the ones you [do] know*** didn't come.

On the other hand:

> ***people** who we don't know from our Sendai factory came to the party*

refers to an *undefined/indefinite* group of people, namely ***[some] people*** from the Sendai factory who you don't know. (It *could* be *all* of them - but that is not specified.)

And similarly:

> ***ones** who we know didn't.*

means ***some of*** the ones you [do] know didn't come.
[In practice, in English you wouldn't say "*ones* who we know"; you would simply say "*some* who we know".

Summarising:

> because ***the*** is the *definite* article, it *does* mean ***all of*** the defined group.
>   because *the absence of an article* with a *plural noun* is equivalent to the *indefinite article* with a *singular noun*, it need not mean all of the group and hence implies ***some of*** the group.

Thus, far from your suggestion that whether the presence or absence of *the* causes it to mean *some* or *all* is merely 'implied, felt, or perceived', it is actually an issue of fundamental grammar.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. How about this:
We went to Disneyland Sunday. As soon as we arrived there, our kids ran to the rides.
The kids cannot run to all the rides there. How do you interpret this as having to do with all-ness? Your enlightenment would be much appreciated.

Comment: They ran to [towards] the [group of] rides [at Disneyland]. They (presumably) didn't **go** on all the rides. The emphasis on "all" in my answer was based on your specific question. In this case, *the* is referring to the specific rides at that location.

Answer (score 1):

As a rough guide, when there is no determiner, this tends to indicate that the entity/entities involved are **indeterminate**: in other words, that the speaker does not see them as a 'list of specific things/people that could be listed/named/individualised'.

So for example in these cases:

> (a) The/some people we had met before came to the party. *(They were Jim, Bill, Karen, Anne...)*
>
> (b) The/some people we didn't know came to the party. *(There were 20 of them. We later learnt they were called Sam, Brenda, Mary...)*

It would potentially make sense to add the part in brackets, 'specifying' the group of people. But in the following cases, adding the bit in brackets sounds slightly odd:

> (c) People we didn't know came to the party. *(??There were 20 of them.)*
>
> (d) People we knew came to the party. *(??They were Brenda, Alan and Dave.)*

So when you use the 'bare' noun without the determiner, you are indicating that the group/entity is 'non-specific'. Because of that, it often sounds pragmatically odd if you go on to specify them as in the parts in brackets in (c) and (d), and if you added the bracketed parts in (c) or (d), it would sound more natural to use the determiner in the first sentence.

Comment: Hello, Neil. That's very informative. Thanks. They say 'the' is used when the referent is 'mutually' specifiable. According to your explanation, it seems like 'the people' are mutually specified to the extent Tom can identify them, and that Sam knows that (he knows they are specifiable). 'Ø people,' on the other hand, are vague. Sam knows Tom cannot tell you who they were, and Sam feels that. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Is the same thing true, Neil, if it's a singular noun like 'the/a man' in the following?

(Suppose there is no context, explicit or implicit, that brings on the definite article in front of 'man' other than, possibly, the relative noun clauses 'who we don't know.')

Tom: The/a man who we don't know from our Sendai factory came to the party.

Sam: Oh, I didn't know you have a factory in Sendai.

(I wrote this dialog, thinking 'we' are Tom and some of his co-workers, and that it doesn't include Sam. Sam is from outside Tom's company)

Comment: I've not heard the condition of them being 'mutually' specifiable before. I suspect it's less of a strict condition: what is probably happening is that, as the speaker, I choose the article according to *my* perception of the universe (or rather, the perception I choose to convey), but that in that choice, there is a phenomenon of *accommodation*: how I choose to portray things will almost always depend on how I know my audience also perceives things.

Comment: Re mass nouns, yes a similar observation holds. If I say "Milk has been spilt on this floor (many times)" -- no article -- I imply that I don't really have a very precise perception of the quantity of milk. But if I say "Some milk has been split on this floor", I indicate that the quantity of milk is roughly known or can be roughly estimated.

Comment: Gee, I like your insights, Neil. Your first comment is very valuable to me as a non-native speaker. Could you please comment on the 'the/a man' chat between Tom and Sam in my second comment? (Suppose there is NO context, explicit of implicit, that brings on the definite article in front of 'man' other than, possibly, the relative pronoun clause 'who we don't know.' [Oooops, it looks like I said 'clauses' in that comment. Obviously, it was a mistake] And 'we' doesn't include Sam)

Comment: With 'the man who we don't know from our Sendai factory came to the party, which you would say out of the blue, would it make sense to add something like 'He is John' afterwards? You would most probably say 'a man' instead, wouldn't you, because the man is somewhat introduced there.

Comment: @Sssamy Remember that the choice of "a" vs "the", independently of the choice of article or no article, is more to do with whether you are introducing 'known' or 'unknown' (or 'previously mentioned' vs 'previously unmentioned') information in terms of the *context* of the conversation, not in terms of whether they're per se known to you or not.

Comment: @Sssamy So if I say "The man we don't know came to the party", even though maybe none of us actually know who the man is, the use of "the" indicates that you will know *which* unknown man I am talking about or at least that that the existence of the unknown person was previously mentioned or obvious to you (e.g. because I have already introduced the topic of conversation and mentioned the presence of an unknown person).