# Should "International community" have a definite article?

Tags: definite-articles

As a non-native English speaker I have always struggled with placing article THE correctly, especially in advanced cases. For example, international community. Does it have to go with the if placed in a sentence and it if does, then why?

P.S. we don't have articles in my mother-tongue so that's why I find it quite difficult.

Comment: You have now asked the international community. You not only need the _the_, you need to pronounce it _thee_ because it is infront of a vovel sound

Comment: Articles are hard. "Why?" is a different question. Perhaps a search for "use of definite article" might help? Or the answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124768/the-primary-determinant-for-deciding-you-should-use-the-or-not).

Comment: (...) placing **the** article "the" correctly (...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no doubt that the use of articles is hard for people whose native languages don't have them. (And even for speakers of other languages that do have articles, it can be difficult, because English and French, say, don't always use them in the same way).

You nearly always need an article here. I'll try to sum up why.

In general, you need an article (*a* or *the*) for a noun phrase unless it is :

- plural (this isn't, even though it might refer to a multiplicity of people or organisations)
- a name
- a quality or abstraction
- an uncountable noun denoting a substance*

Now some people will say that *community* is always an abstract noun; but I'll argue that it can be, but is usually not.

You can talk about *the ideal of international community*: there it is an abstract idea or quality, and doesn't take an article. But in most uses, though it is abstract in a way, it stands for a collection of real things: people, or countries, or organisations. Something that you can talk to, steal from, corrupt. So it is not "a quality or abstraction" in the way I meant these, and requires an article.

So *international community* almost always denotes a thing in the world (even though it is quite a vague sort of thing) and needs an article. Only if it is used in the rather rare sense of an ideal or quality does it not take an article.

[*This possibility was added in an edit, in response to a comment from Araucaria]

Comment: This is a great answer, Colin, thank you very much! I knew about the first two cases when an article is not needed, but I was not aware of the third one. All is clear now.

Comment: @Araucaria: true. I've now added it.